# Use node.js to determine if in git directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash

I am trying to determine if my node process is running in a git directory. The following works, but is still outputting a fatal error in the console.

```
function testForGit() {
    try {
        var test = execSync('git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree', {encoding: 'utf8'});
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return !!test;
}

console.log(testForGit());
```

When in a directory under the control of git, I get `true` as the result. But when outside of a directory under the control of git, I get:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
false
```

**My question(s):**

Is there a way to suppress the error being logged? Or **is there a better way** to determine if I am in a directory under git control?

Essentially, I am trying to do the bash equivalent of

```
if git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    ... do something
fi
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate attempt at a legitimate problem...

Comment: seems like looking for the hidden `.git` folder would be simpler/faster....

Comment: @dandavis, I thought about that, but wasn't sure what kind of repercussions there would be for recursively running up parent directories until I hit the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to redirect `stdout` inside the `execSync` call, like this:

```
var test = execSync('git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null', {encoding: 'utf8'});
```

Comment: Caution: This is true even if your user is within a subdirectory of a git repo.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `docker` and don't want to install `git` as a system-level dependency when build image for your application. Maybe because we want to build the image faster and keep the image size as small as possible.

The way @janos provides will not work.

Another way is to check is there a `.git` directory or not in root path of your project. But it depends on your requirements. For my case, it's enough.

```js
exports.isGitSync = function isGitSync (dir) {
  return fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, '.git'))
}
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer since you don't actually need `git`. And sync operations are allowed when starting a node process. Also you may check for the config file and return it's contents that contains also the remote-origin of the repository.